# How can I use workflow to append field values?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have a field in called "Notes" in two separate lists. When an item is created in list 2 I have a workflow that copies the Notes over.

On an update to list 2, I would like it to append the notes from list 2 into list 1. Can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. Here are the steps:

In the Actions step, do the following:

```
1. Click on Actions -> Assign workflow variable
2. Set Variable:MyVariable to List2:Notes2
3. Click Actions -> Build Dynamic String
4. then Store [%Variable:MyVariable%] <your custom string goes here> in Varibale:MyVariable
5. Click Actions -> Update List Item
6. the Update item in List1
```

Let me know if this makes sense and you are able to achieve your goal. Happy coding!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 2010 workflow you can use

```
Set History to [%Current Item:History%] [%Current Item:Notes%]
```