# How do I add leading zeros to a variable in Sharepoint 2010 site workflow?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I'm using Sharepoint 2013, but this particular site workflow is a 2010 version. I'm trying to accomplish this in Sharepoint Designer.

This workflow creates a new document, and assigns a given number to it. To determine the number I'm retrieving a numeric value from a particular list. After getting this value I need to add leading zeros to it before concatenating it with another string. For instance, the value I get back might be 4, and I want it to have a total of 3 characters, so in this case 004. A value of 12 should be formatted 012, and so on.

An alternate approach I tried was using calculated fields rather than putting this together within the workflow. Unfortunately this isn't a comprehensive solution for me as I need the formatted value available as a Word Quick Part, and as far as I know calculated fields cannot be used for this.

Comment: check this one http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24858/how-can-i-use-workflow-to-append-field-values

Comment: I don't have the "Build Dynamic String" option as an available action. I'm guessing that's in a different type of workflow. I had to use a 2010 workflow in order to get the document created properly (based on a word template) as doing this via a 2013 workflow always created a corrupt file.

Comment: I think "build dynamic string" is the old name. You cannot find this action but you can still use the function. [Check it out](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/55ad87bc-c990-47fb-a87e-c46d8ea5d632/build-dynamic-string-missingrenamed?forum=sharepointcustomization)

Answer (score 4):

following solution worked for me:
https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Auto-Incrementing-Document-IDs-Help-43166.S.196916024

After I tried all kinds of formula's, solution turned out to be much easier, say: plain simple.

Solution from the link above:

If you need the leading 0s and I understand what you're looking for correctly, I think it can be accomplished with three SharePoint Designer workflow actions and using the ID field on the document library: 
-Create a column that will be your DocId and set it as type "single line of text"

-You'll want to modify that column in the Content Type definition to be of type Hidden so that users can't modify this column when editing properties of a document in the library.

- Create a SPD workflow and add a "Set Workflow Variable" action. Create a new variable "TempDocId" and when you set the value select the ... button and then type in 0000000 then press the "Add or Change Lookup" and insert a reference to the ID column of the current item. This gives you a variable that has the unique ID plus (too many) 0s in front of it
- Next add the "Extract substring from end of string" workflow action. Change the number 0 to 6 and change the text "string" to be a reference to the workflow variable we created above "TempDocId".
- Finally add a "Set Field in Current Item" workflow action and set the current item's DocId field to the value that's in the "substring" workflow variable (result from above).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula and set the result to a variable. Or use this in a calculated field

```
=CONCATENATE("STRINGTOPREFIX",REPT("0",MAX(0,3-LEN(ID))),ID)
```

Replace ID with the value you read from the list.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've tried something very similar to this (and it's how I previously got the calculated field to properly concatenate those values). Trouble is, I can't get this formula to work inside of a workflow. It adds the number, but treats the rest of it as a string, and ignores the Concatenate and Rept functions (interpreting that as part of the string).

Comment: I think you should break the steps (1) Read the number (2) set variable and use the `REPT` to format the number (3) concatenate

Comment: Same result, unfortunately. The string builder in the workflow doesn't seem to recognize the functions. The exact contents of my example is: 

=REPT("0",MAX(0,3-LEN([%Variable: AutoNum%])))

But for a value of AutoNum of 10, instead of the output being 010, it's "=REPT("0",MAX(0,3-LEN(10)))"

Comment: Ok then I think event receivers is the next option. Or use IF conditions and check the length then add 0 and build the string.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a sandboxed custom workflow action for this kind of requirements. You can simply write an AddLeadingZeros custom action and use it in your workflows.

I appreciate this requires Visual Studio etc to develop, but I did this only once, I maintain a solution which holds all sorts of small actions to do this kind of tasks and I simply add a few lines when I need a new functionality.

Here is a link on how to do it: [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff798499.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a calculated value field, then in the workflow assign a text field to that calculated value.   Then you can use that text field in other areas where you cannot use a calculated value. Such as an indexed field.  I'm doing this in Sharepoint Online and SPD 2013 for the workflow.